# setState is working within some parts of my JSX but not others

Tags: reactjs

```
const [collateralSize, setCollateralSize] = useState(0)
```

With this input, typing a value in it sets the value to the typed value and also stores it in collateralSize (though I do note the console.log is a "step behind")

```
<InputStyled
    onChange={(e) => {
            setCollateralSize(parseFloat(e.target.value))
            console.log('collateralSize', collateralSize)
    }}
    value={collateralSize}
    type="number"
/>
```

It also updates this component automatically:

```
 <CalculationValue>{collateralSize}</CalculationValue>
```

But this component there is a problem:

```
<SlideComponent
    onSlide={(a, b) => {
        console.log(collateralSize)
    }}
/>
```

After typing numbers in InputStyle (which updates), and also seeing CalculationValue also update, when I then slide my slideComponent, the console.log(CalculationValue) is 0. Why doesn't it update like the InputStyled and CalculationValue do?